# when condition fails in ansible

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible

I have a simple playbook that loads data to different instances based on the `DEPLOY_TO` environment variable that is entered from jenkins which has the value `dev` and `test`. By comparing the `{{ lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') }}`  variable with `dev` or `test` using `when` condition

```
- name: load loadBase files into target mysql dev
  shell: mysql -h {{ lookup('env','db_host_dev') }} -u {{ lookup('env','db_user_dev') }} --password={{ lookup('env','db_root_password_dev') }} {{ lookup('env','db_name') }} < /tmp/{{ item | basename }}
  with_items: "{{ data.loadBase }}"
  no_log: false
  when: "{{ lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') }} == dev"
          
- name: load loadBase files into target mysql test
  shell: mysql -h {{ lookup('env','db_host_test') }} -u {{ lookup('env','db_user_test') }} --password={{ lookup('env','db_root_password_test') }} {{ lookup('env','db_name') }} < /tmp/{{ item | basename }}
  with_items: "{{ data.loadBase }}"
  no_log: false
  when: "{{ lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') }} == test"
```

But when running the pipeline to `DEPLOY_TO` either dev or test, it fails with the following error

```
18:34:15  [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
18:34:15  delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') }} ==
18:34:15  dev
18:34:15  fatal: [10.0.1.78]: FAILED! => {
18:34:15      "msg": "The conditional check '{{ lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') }} == dev' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') }} == dev): 'dev' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/deploy/jenkins/workspace/infrastructure/deploy.yml': line 77, column 11, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n        - name: load loadBase files into target mysql dev\n          ^ here\n"
```

May I please know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems, both called out in the error messages. The first is:

```
conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
```

The value of a `when` condition is already evaluated in an implicit template context; you don't need (and shouldn't add) `{{...}}` markers around (or anywhere inside) the expression. That gets you:

```
  when: "lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') == dev"
```

That gets you to the second error:

```
The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') }} == dev): 'dev' is undefined
```

You're comparing the result of the `lookup` to a *variable* named `dev`. If you meant to compare it to a literal string, you need to quote it (just like in the arguments to `lookup`):

```
  when: "lookup('env','DEPLOY_TO') == 'dev'"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for pointing it out. This really helped and solved the issue